# Zoom image using css

Tags: html, css, hover, zooming

I am trying to zoom image on mouseover. I am getting the zoom effect, but the image should zoom within that "list" tag, not out of that "list". What should I do to get zoom effect like a pop up?

I have applied CSS to the list to make it horizontal, like:

`image1  image2 image3 .....` in ul and li tag.

```css
.thumbnail_img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    /*right:420px;*/
}

.thumbnail_img:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 100;
}

.thumbnail_img span img { 
    display: inline-block;
    margin:-13px 17px 2px -13px;
}

.thumbnail_img span { 
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transform:scale(0.8);
    -moz-transform:scale(0.8);
    -o-transform:scale(0.8);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.thumbnail_img:hover span { /*CSS for enlarged image on hover*/
    visibility: visible;
    background: transparent;
    top: 0px;
    left:5px;
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform:scale(1.2);
    -o-transform:scale(1.2);
    opacity: 3;
    height:auto; width:auto;
    border:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="mytest" id="slideshow-carousel" style="padding-top:12px;padding-left: 33px;">
    <ul id="carousel" class="jcarousel jcarousel-skin-tango">
        <li>
            <a href="#" rel="p1"  class="thumbnail_img"> <img src="image.jpg " width="55" height="60" alt="#"/>
                <span><img src="image.jpg" style="height:100px; width:100px" /></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" rel="p1"  class="thumbnail_img"> <img src=" " width="55" height="60" alt="#"/>
                <span><img src="" style="height:100px; width:100px" /></span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give more info? Is not clear what you try to achieve

Comment: Change the `top` and `left` values on `.thumbnail_img:hover span`

Comment: @Tom sarduy:Zoom image on mouseover(actual size width=55,height=60")

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
.thumbnail_img img:hover
{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    -o-transform: scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

If you don't wanna overflow li then add

```
.thumbnail_img li
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: :Getting zoom but within <li> </li>.

Comment: You can try and increase your z-index but sometimes z-index doesn't help much if you want your container has a less z-index than from the one you want to zoom out. It would be good you can show me exactly how you wish to zoom out with the source files

Answer (score 3):

The image zoom's within that list since you assign relative to .thumbnail_img (which within the list) and this makes it becomes the anchor of absolute positioned image, I've slightly adjust your style as below to make the image zoom's outside the list:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                /* move position: relative from .thumbnail_img to body*/
                position: relative;
            }
            .thumbnail_img{
                /*position: relative;*/
                z-index: 0;
                /*right:420px;*/
            }

            .thumbnail_img:hover {
                background-color: transparent;
                z-index: 100;
            }

            .thumbnail_img span img { 
                display: inline-block;
                margin:-13px 17px 2px -13px;
            }

            .thumbnail_img span { 
                position: absolute;
                visibility: hidden;
                color: black;
                text-decoration: none;
                -webkit-transform:scale(0.8);
                -moz-transform:scale(0.8);
                -o-transform:scale(0.8);
                -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
                -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
                -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
                opacity: 0.7;
            }

            .thumbnail_img:hover span { /*CSS for enlarged image on hover*/
                visibility: visible;
                background: transparent;
                top: 250px;
                left:500px;
                -webkit-transform:scale(5);
                -moz-transform:scale(5);
                -o-transform:scale(5);
                opacity: 3;
                height:auto; width:auto;
                border:0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="mytest" id="slideshow-carousel" style="padding-top:12px;padding-left: 33px;">
            <ul id="carousel" class="jcarousel jcarousel-skin-tango">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" rel="p1"  class="thumbnail_img"> <img src="image.jpg" width="55" height="60" alt="#"/>
                        <span><img src="image.jpg" style="height:100px; width:100px" /></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" rel="p1"  class="thumbnail_img"> <img src=" " width="55" height="60" alt="#"/>
                        <span><img src="" style="height:100px; width:100px" /></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @benbail1:Not getting zoom outof <li>.

Comment: what is your 'out of' mean? The position or the thumb one should disappeared? By the way, what is your target browsers?

Comment: :image zoom using above css code but its block within Height of list.

Comment: I see, then try the updated sample, the top, left and scale of .thumbnail_img:hover span are updated

Answer (score 1):

- **Zoom image on mouse hover !!**

```css
.pic{
 width:200px;
 height:120px;
}
.zoom{
 position: absolute;
 width:0px;
 -webkit-transition:width 0.3s linear 0s;
 transition:width 0.3s linear 0s;
 z-index:10;
}
.pic:hover + .zoom{
 width:400px;

}
```

```html
<img class="pic" src="http://lamina17.info/image/cpp.png" alt="image">
<img class="zoom" src="http://lamina17.info/image/cpp.png" alt="image">
```

---

See Demo here [Zoom Image Using Css](http://lamina17.info/code/html5/zoom.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>img:hover{transform:scale(1.2)}</style>
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/73/7d/ac/737dac12b48b03cd97fb6152dfa023b4.jpg">
```

[image: transform image]

Comment: Could you be more descriptive?

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.